# VBA slows over time - can I load my object into memory to speed things up?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm running vba in excel to read paragraphs from a word document.  The code works fine, however, I'm reading 10000 paragraphs and by the time I get to the end the loop is crawling.  I wanted to try reading the word doc into memory then attempting the loop to see if it speeds up.  The thing is that I'm not sure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Here is what I currently have

```
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)
Set myParas = wdDoc.Paragraphs
ParCount = myParas.Count

For X = 0 To ParCount  ' ParCount is 10,000
    With myParas(X)
        pLevel = .OutlineLevel
    End With
Next X
```

Comment: What is "do stuff"?  It's pretty easy to get all the document text as a `String`, but whether that's useful depends on what you intend to do with it.

Comment: Use `For Each` loop instead of For loop

Comment: Why do you need to load all these paragraphs into memory at one time? Do you need them all available at the same time? If you really have to, consider storing them in a database instead.

Comment: If that's your actual code then no wonder it doesn't work :) Please read how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Most of the time stuff just loads into memory anyway without any explicit code to do so. Problem could be that you're _running out_ of memory and it's doing the work on disk. If you go into task manager how much memory are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Word doesn't know the position of each paragraph, so when using `document.Paragraphs(1234)` it has to start searching from the first paragraph.
 That is why `For Each` would be much faster than `For`:

```
Dim p As Word.Paragraph

For Each p in document.Paragraphs
    ' do stuff
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a shot.  Perhaps I wasn't clear enough with my request - 1st time posting here and half the pseudo code got lost.  Anyway, this sounds like what I was looking for so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Outstanding!  Solved my problem. Looping on the collection is lightning fast...compared to the For/Next option. Thanks.