# How can I speed up my directory-find-and-highlight VBA script?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a very simple series of functions to find-and-highlight paragraphs of text containing certain terms within a series of documents in the same directory. Although functional, the code is extremely slow to run over some documents, the characteristics of which I have not yet really established (although I suspect they may either be text-box-heavy, or may just include a lot of blank paragraphs being tested for nothing - more on this later).

Here is the code:

```
Sub FindCheeses()
    Dim x As Object
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim strFilePattern As String
    Dim strFileName
    Dim sFileName As String

    sFolder = "X:\Menus\"
    strFilePattern = "*.docx"
    strFileName = Dir(sFolder & strFilePattern)
    Do Until strFileName = vbNullString
        sFileName = sFolder & strFileName
        Set x = Documents.Open(sFileName)
        Call HighlightCheeses(x)
        ActiveDocument.Close (wdSaveChanges)

        Set x = Nothing
        strFileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub

Function HighlightCheeses(oWordDoc)
    Call HighlightStuff("roquefort", "cheddar", "wensleydale", oWordDoc)
End Function

Function HighlightStuff(x, y, z, oWordDoc) As String
    Dim rngStory As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim xPos As Integer, yPos As Integer, zPos As Integer
    Dim para As String

    For Each rngStory In oWordDoc.StoryRanges
        For i = 1 To rngStory.Paragraphs.Count
            para = rngStory.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
            If para <> vbNullString Then
                xPos = InStr(1, para, x, vbBinaryCompare)
                yPos = InStr(1, para, y, vbBinaryCompare)
                zPos = InStr(1, para, z, vbBinaryCompare)
                If xPos <> 0 Then
                    rngStory.Paragraphs(i).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                End If
                If yPos <> 0 Then
                    rngStory.Paragraphs(i).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                End If
                If zPos <> 0 Then
                    rngStory.Paragraphs(i).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next
End Function
```

I know it's a weird way to have written the code but I was trying to make it relatively simple for someone else to adapt.  Is that what is causing it to run slowly in some cases?  For some reason the test for whether the text of a paragraph is not empty always seems to succeed - that could also be the reason but I'm not sure how to resolve.

Very grateful for any advice - hope this question fits the guidelines!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730313/vba-slows-over-time-can-i-load-my-object-into-memory-to-speed-things-up/41731094#41731094

Comment: YowE3K, thanks for your edit. Slai, thanks so much for your response - this helped speed up my code by many times.

Comment: In fact, it's probably going to help speed up every piece of code I ever write.  Thanks again.